# (LP problem) Find an optimal plane that contains a set of points in its positive half-space, such that it does not coincide with another plane

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, computational-geometry, polytopes, point-cloud

Given is a set of points $S = \{s_1,...,s_N\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$ and a plane $H_1$ with $H_1^+ = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n ~\vert~ n_1^Tx - b_1  \geq 0\}$ being its positive half-space, such that $\forall s\in S : s \in H_1^+$ and $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{s\in S} (n_1^Ts - b_1)$ is minimized. Such a plane can be found by solving an LP of the form $$ \min F^T z\\ \text{subject to} \\ \forall s\in S: \begin{pmatrix}-s^T&1\end{pmatrix}z \leq 0, \\
       -F^T z \leq -1, $$ where $F = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{s\in S} s\\-1\end{pmatrix}$.

That works. Now however I want to find an additional plane $H_2$ with normal $n_2$ and bias $b_2$, which also satisfies the above criteria and it potentially intersects, but is not equal to $H_1$.

My question is how to formulate this as an LP in order to find $n_2$ and $b_2$.

More contextually my problem is about finding planes $H_1,...,H_p$ which form a polytope $P = \bigcap_{i=1}^p H_i^+$, such that $\text{conv}S \subseteq P$. My approach (and hence the question) is to start with an initial plane $H_1$ and solving extra LPs for each new plane, until a bounding polytope is found.

Any advice or perhaps an alternative approach would be greatly appreciated. I admit that my knowledge of linear programming is quite limited but I am slowly catching up.

EDIT: To clarify the general problem a bit, I am not trying to find the convex hull, but rather an over-approximation of it given a fixed number of $p = n+k$ faces.

Comment: I haven't read this carefully - but perhaps you are looking for the _convex hull_ of the original set of points. There are well known algorithms for that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: Hi, no. The goal is to find an over-approximation of the convex hull. I will correct the question to clarify this.

Comment: is this for a research project?

Comment: The condition that a hyperplane does not equal a given hyperplane is not convex, and therefore, cannot be expressed with purely linear constraints.

Comment: Yes it is for a research project. Indeed I was worried that I cannot express this as a linear constraint. I was thinking of the constraint, assuming that $\lVert n_1 \rVert = 1$, that $\frac{n_1^Tn_2}{\lVert n_2 \rVert} \leq n^{-1}$, where 'n' is dimension. Then the problem is about LP with 1 non-linear constraint.

Comment: you can always find a cube that encloses all your points; how does your ideal solution differ from a cube?

Comment: In general you can maximize a support function of $S$ in $p$ directions. A rectangular hull, as you propose, is a special case when $p = 2n$ and half of the direction vectors are orthogonal to each other. My ideal solution however would choose $p > n$ directions, such that the $Vol(P)$ is minimized and the amount of vertices of $P$ is polynomial w.r.t. $n$. A cube has $2^n$ vertices, which is not ideal.